# Angular2 Router - Anyone know how to use canActivate in app.ts so that I can redirect to home page if not logged in

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Angular2 Router - Anyone know how to use canActivate in app.ts so that I can redirect to home page if not logged in

I'm using typescript and angular 2.

**Current attempt under my constructor in my app.ts file:**

```
   canActivate(instruction) {           
               console.log("here - canActivate");
               console.log(instruction);

               this.router.navigate(['Home']);  
   }
```

It currently doesnt get hit.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 12):

So the documentation looks like this is what it exports.

```
export CanActivate(options : CanActivateAnnotation) : (hook: (next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) =>
                     Promise<boolean>| boolean) => ClassDecorator

@CanActivate((next, prev) => {
      // This must prove to be true for the component @ this route to load
      if(next.urlPath != '/Login'){ 
         return Promise.resolve(this._authService.getIsAuth() 
         && localStorage.getItem('authToken')
      }
      /*
       If CanActivate returns or resolves to false, the navigation is 
       cancelled. If CanActivate throws or rejects, the navigation is also
       cancelled. If CanActivate returns or resolves to true, navigation 
       continues, the component is instantiated, and the OnActivate hook of 
       that component is called if implemented.
      */
   }
);
```

At the bottom of the Angular2 documentation they add this snippet : 
exported from angular2/router 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html

So if you are looking to do redirection from a higher level.
You would not use the CanActivate decorator you would do the following.

```
import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';
import {Login} from '../login/login';
import {UserService} from '../../Services/userService'; // a service to handle auth

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class AuthRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  publicRoutes: any;
  private parentRouter: Router;

  constructor(private _userService:UserService, _elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
              _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    this.publicRoutes = {
      '/login': true,
      '/signup': true
    };
    // publicRoutes will be the routes auth is not needed for.
  }

  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    var url = this.parentRouter.lastNavigationAttempt;
    if (!this.publicRoutes[url] && this._userService.getAuth()) {
      // todo: redirect to Login, may be there a better way?
      this.parentRouter.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
    return super.activate(instruction);
    // we return super.activate(instruction) here so the router can activate the requested route and it's components.
  }
}
```

This implementation handles any new request to a  directive and runs the activate function where your route authentication logic will be.
The code above would be called something like AuthRouterOutlet.
and you would have to add it to your app.ts via the

```
directives: [ AuthRouterOutlet]
```

Comment: Where do I import this annotation from?

Comment: I added it to my answer it`s in angular2/router

Comment: Can I add the @CanActivate to my app.ts file? Because I want to redirect the user to another route if they are not authenticated

Comment: I think you will need to put it on the components where you want to over ride their navigation.

Comment: I want it in a global area like app ts so I can redirect if users try to reach pages without logging in

Comment: I added the higher level route authentication to my answer.

Comment: I've implement your answer above but do I need to link it to my app,ts file? because its not hitting the LoggedInRouterOutlet code above

Comment: Ok I've got it hitting it, but it still hits the internal page component

Comment: could you put it in a plnkr just your app.ts file

Comment: Not sure how to do that.

Comment: This is my current code :  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    this.parentRouter.navigate(['/Home']); 
    return super.activate(instruction);
  }

Comment: For some pages it navigates to Home and for other pages that are internal it doesnt, thus causing a component error as its hitting the component

Comment: remove the return statement.. What happens if you do that? If you return super.activate(instruction) it will continue to the navigated route and not redirect.

Comment: I get typescript error - property activate are incompatible

Comment: Are you sure you are using the <LoggedInRouterOutlet></LoggedInRouterOutlet> tag instead of <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: I didnt do that, I have now and none of my routes work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101694/discussion-between-inoabrian-and-angularm).

Comment: any luck with the redirect to home route ?

Comment: @inoabrian Can you show us an example of how to use LoggedInRouterOutlet? How do you register it in boot.ts? I am currently getting "Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Router'(?, ?, ?)". Thanks.

Comment: superb solution...bravo !

Comment: `ComponentInstruction` does not exist yet in the new v 3.0.0.0-alpha8 router. How do we get around this?

Comment: This is a common requirement and core behavior that the framework can and should provide. It's not the case that thousands of developers should hack together an override of the routing function.

Answer (score 5):

With the new beta release of the router, you can also see my answer here on how to use the CanActivate interface:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38369948/1944351

Using the decorator as mentioned in other answer is fine too.

Answer (score 2):

These answers are no longer valid in the RC candidate as of 22/6/16.

There is a lot of talk a new solution for `@CanActivate` annotation but you can revert back to using the `angular-2/router-deprecated` version in the interim.

If you want to follow the updates to this area if you want to use the newer router implementation please check out these two github issues:

- [Router OnActivate does not delay render until promise settles #6611](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6611)
- [Equivalent to resolve in Component Router? #4015](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4015)

Sorry there is no complete answer right now, if I see any further progress on this I'll update this reply. I'm searching for an elegant solution as well.

For the interim I just used a `ngIf='fooObject'` in a div to check for object being used in a child directive is populated/truthy and then render the rest of the components html. It's not ideal but it does work consistently right now. May help you or not depending on your use case. I don't need to redirect, only check my data has resolved for the display of my component.

Answer (score 1):

From here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html

`CanActivate` is an annotation, not a function. You use it like this:

```
@Component({selector: ... })
@CanActivate(()=>console.log('Should the component Activate?'))
class AppComponent {

}
```

`routerOnActivate` IS a function you use inside your component:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html

Comment: for the routerOnActivate where do I import it from?

Comment: The angular.io documentation is poor for examples.

Comment: The @CanActivate(()=>console.log('Should the component Activate?')) code doesnt seem to work

Comment: from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html, you import the OnActivate interface , but its not necesary, as long as your Component has that method, the router will call it if your method gets resolved by a route

Comment: And I can put this in my app.ts file?

Comment: Have you gone through the `<router-outlet>` at all?

Comment: @AngularM - looks like the routerOnActivate is from the following.
exported from angular2/router defined in angular2/src/router/interfaces.ts (line 7)

Comment: @inoabrian  did you get anywhere with the redirect to homepage?

Answer (score 0):

@CanActivate was removed. See more details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8655).

You should now use [route.canActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html)