# What's the best way to provide isAdmin() function to @CanActivate

Tags: angular

So I've been skimming through many blogs/tutorials trying to figure this out but to no avail.

What I want is to be able to pass to `@CanActivate()` functions which are supposed to figure out if the user is logged in. I have tried making a static function

```
static isUserInjector() {
    return (next, prev) => Injector.resolveAndCreate([AuthService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]).get(AuthService).isUser();
}
```

inside my AuthService class so I just import it into the directive's .ts and call the static function but this seems a bit clumsy and I don't feel too good using this Injector because I suppose I was to bootstrap everything I'd need but I don't know how to get to it outside of my components. (I know only that you can get to the bootstrapped services by 'demanding' the in the constructor.

Is dependency injection a wrong pattern to go with @CanActivate?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my answer to a similar question here: [Angular2 Router - Anyone know how to use canActivate in app.ts so that I can redirect to home page if not logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754295/angular2-router-anyone-know-how-to-use-canactivate-in-app-ts-so-that-i-can-red/34759270?noredirect=1#comment57283408_34759270)

I explain how to extend the router-outlet for route authentication.
Hope it helps.