# Good way to secure multiple Angular 2 components

Tags: angular

A common recommended way to secure Angular 2 component/routes seems to be to use `@CanActivate()`, like here:

http://youknowriad.github.io/angular2-cookbooks/stateless-authentication.html

If you have only a few components this works fine, but is there a better way that would centralize all this?

Would having a common base class for each component work? (any examples on how to do this?). Could we have a custom `@CanActivate()`, something like `@ProtectMyApp()`? (examples?)

I'm basically trying to prevent having to copy+paste the same `@CanActivate()` code for each component.

(apologies if these questions do not make sense, still learning Angular)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754295/angular2-router-anyone-know-how-to-use-canactivate-in-app-ts-so-that-i-can-red/34759270?noredirect=1#comment57283408_34759270

Comment: @inoabrian yes, that's very close to what I'm after. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to use that, getting "Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Router'(?, ?, ?)"

Answer (score 6):

You can create a global callback that you can pass into the `@CanActivate` decorator:

```
export function isAllowed(): boolean | Promise<boolean>{
    // Permission logic here
}
```

and then you can pass that function into the decorator

```
@Component({...})
@CanActivate(isAllowed)
export class MyComponent{

}
```

This would give you a global source of validating permission, but still use the built in methods.

**Update**

*This is untested but might work for injecting a service into `isAllowed`*

In the documentation I found that the `bootstrap` method returns a `ComponentRef` which has an `injector` property that has the following comment in the docs

> The injector provided DynamicComponentLoader.

This could be the golden ticket for getting the same singleton instance that is used by the main injector for the application. In theory this should work

In your startup file

```
export var applicationInjector: Injector;
bootstrap(AppComponent, [MyService, ...]).then((ref: ComponentRef) => {
    applicationInjector = ref.injector;
});
```

Then in the file with your isAllowed method

```
import {applicationInjector} from '...';

export function isAllowed(): boolean | Promise<boolean>{
    let myService: MyService = applicationInjector.get(MyService);
    return myService.isAllowed();
}
```

Comment: Ideally, I would like to use a service that I would inject into "isAllowed()". Is that possible?

Comment: I'm sure it is, but I haven't yet figured out how to hack into the `Injector` of the running application. You could of course use your own `Injector` or simply `new` the service yourself. But that would then be a different instance then the one running elsewhere in your application.

Comment: Actually I just found something that might work, but I don't really know, haven't tried it. I'll update my answer with the code.