# Accessing root Angular 2 injector instance globally

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

How to access an instance of root Angular 2 injector globally (say, from browser console).

In Angular 1 it was `angular.element(document).injector()`.

It can be useful during testing and exploration, to use browser console to get injector to then access instances of different components, directives, services etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must set it into a service after bootstrapping the application:

```
export var applicationInjector: Injector;

bootstrap([AppComponent]).then((componentRef: ComponentRef) => {
  applicationInjector = componentRef.injector;
});
```

Then you can import it into other parts of your application:

```
import {applicationInjector} from './bootstrap';
```

See this question for more details:

- [Good way to secure multiple Angular 2 components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190844/good-way-to-secure-multiple-angular-2-components/35190965#35190965)

**Edit**

You can inject the `ApplicationRef` into components and have access to the root injector through it:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private app:ApplicationRef) {
    var rootInjector = app.injector;
  }
}
```

You need to leverage dependency injection to get it.

Comment: Is the instance of `ComponentRef` saved anywhere by Angular 2 and available globally (something like for example `ng.core.rootComponent()`)? In any case saving it manually is more work than what was available in Angular 1, but is still fine.

Comment: For the root component I don't think. That being said you can inject the `ApplicationRef` into your component and get access to the root injector. No need to save it manually ;-) I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: In current Angular (2.4.4) ```ApplicationRef``` does not have a public property ```injector```; apparently it was made private.

Comment: @willydee, check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43593211/2545680) for the newest version

Comment: @RPDeshaies, check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43593211/2545680) for the newest version

Comment: @ThierryTemplier, check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43593211/2545680) for the newest version

Comment: Wow, no more `ReflectiveInjector` or `StaticInjector` headaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

In Angular `v.4.x.x` the root injector is located on the [PlatformRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/PlatformRef-class.html). You can access it like this:

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// create a platform    
let platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

// save reference to the global object
window['rootInjector'] = platform.injector;

// boostrap application
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Or inside any component like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(platform: PlatformRef) {
      console.log(platform.injector);
```

But the `root` injector is pretty useless. It contains mostly compiler and platform specific data and helpers:

```
[
  "InjectionToken Platform ID",
  "PlatformRef_",
  "PlatformRef",
  "Reflector",
  "ReflectorReader",
  "TestabilityRegistry",
  "Console",
  "InjectionToken compilerOptions",
  "CompilerFactory",
  "InjectionToken Platform Initializer",
  "PlatformLocation",
  "InjectionToken DocumentToken",
  "InjectionToken Platform: browserDynamic",
  "InjectionToken Platform: coreDynamic",
  "InjectionToken Platform: core"
]
```

You're probably looking for `AppModule` injector which you can get like this:

```
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((module) => {
  window['rootInjector'] = module.injector;
});
```

You can extract [ApplicationRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html#!#components-anchor) or root [ComponentRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentRef-class.html) from it:

```
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((module) => {
  let applicationRef = module.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
  let rootComponentRef = applicationRef.components[0];
});
```

Also, if Angular is running in the development mode, you can get either AppModule or lazy loaded NgModule injector like this:

```
ng.probe($0).injector.view.root.ngModule
```

Comment: `ng.probe($0).injector.view.root.ngModule` this way you can get either `AppModule` or lazy loaded `NgModule` injector

Comment: @yurzui, yes, but only if not `enableProdMode()`

Comment: He asked `It can be useful during testing and exploration` so it would be helpful :)

Comment: @yurzui, yeah, thanks, I'll add to the answer. I've also found an amazing way to subscribe to application bootstrap process :). I'll write an article about it

Comment: @yurzui, thanks for the links, interesting. It seems I got it right with hierarchy of injectors :)

Comment: But beetween elInjectors there are router-outlet injectors :) So my schema is not full

Comment: @yurzui, I'll take a look, thanks. I was thinking about writing about injector hierarchy. Whose presentations are these?

Comment: @yurzui, I requested access. Judging by the name on the presentation you seem to be speaking Russian. Do you?

Comment: Yes i do. I gave the access

Comment: @yurzui, yeah, quite a lot :) what country? try mine `live:m.koretskyi`

Comment: Is using `bootstrapModule(AppModule).then()` to get a global reference to the AppModule injector not a bit late? The application will have been loaded at this stage - so any calls to `window['rootInjector']` during startup will fail. I used `AppModule constructor` with injected `Injector`, and set that as the global. Is that an equivalent solution, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Drenai, can you set up a demo on stackblitz? I'll take a look

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I've tested it already. The `AppModule` and `AppComponent` constructors are called before `bootstrapModule promise` resolves - so too late to use for global injector. We can use the AppModule constructor to set the global `injector` instance, or the APP_INITIALIZER process. Here's a demo of AppModule approach (with console logs to show same instance of DemoService being provided) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2jwz4p

Answer (score 2):

Here is another take for Angular 9.

Open the JavaScript console on the page of your Angular application that is not in the production node.

Find the `<app-root>` on the page:

```js
root = document.querySelector("app-root");
```

Get the injector. The `ng()` helper is a global that is available if the app is in development mode:

```js
injector = ng.getInjector("app-root");
```

Injector would allow you to get services by their class name. Unfortunately, I do not know if or how Angular service classes are available through the `window` namespace.

So our next attempt is to get services from the components of the already visible elements on the page.

```js
appComponent = ng.getComponent(root)
```

This way you get access to any `AppComponent` variables e.g. "UserService" your app might have.

```js
appComponent.userService
```

```
UserService {http: HttpService, userSubject: BehaviorSubject}
```

Now you can call the service from the console:

```js
appComponent.userService.userSubject.value.userEmail
```

```
mikko@capitalgram.com
```

You can also access components that are not the application root, and get access to services bound to them. First we need to navigate to the page where the component appears. This will trigger the actual transition in the UI.

```
await appComponent.router.navigate(["/another-page"])
```

Now you can get hold of any visible component by its tag name:

```js
elem = document.querySelector("app-my-component")
component = ng.getComponent(elem)
```

And you can see its services:

```
MyComponent(envService, http, sanitizer);
```

And you can poke them, with all your user tokens, sessions, etc. in place:

```js
component.envService.getConfigValue()
```