# Inject a service on the console in angular2

Tags: angular, inject, angular2-services

How do I inject a service in angular2 in the console?

In angular1 just wrote:

```
angular.element(document).injector().get('MyService')
```

Comment: May this blogpost helps http://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/debugging-angular2-console/

Comment: just tried. ng.probe($0) returns undefined

Comment: ahhhh it works. But only, if you select the root component in the browser developer tools before. That's no option. Is there any option to select the root component automatically without $0 ?

Comment: ng.probe($0).componentInstance.MyService.myMethodCall() works, but i want it without $0. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing root Angular 2 injector instance globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455305/accessing-root-angular-2-injector-instance-globally)