# What's the right way to access Angular on the console (from devtools) in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, console, google-chrome-devtools, angular8

I'm running Angular 8.  Following the probably outdated advice here -- [How can I test an AngularJS service from the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527832/how-can-i-test-an-angularjs-service-from-the-console), I'm trying to access an Angular service from the Chrome devtools console.  Below is the disappointing output

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
injector = angular.element(document.body).injector()
VM914:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

What's the right way to access Angular on the command line in Angular 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just save a reference of injector class globally

*main.ts*

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';


if (environment.production) { //  production
  enableProdMode();
} else { //  development
  const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
  window['injector'] = platform.injector;
}
```

[Injector](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector)

**Updated!!**

onther option without store a reference of the injector globaly

```js
const inj = ng.probe(document.querySelector('app-root')).injector;
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to do this without modifying my existing code.  It seemed possible in older version of Angular

Comment: click on `app-root` then `const e =$0;  ng.probe(e).injector`

Comment: check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455305/accessing-root-angular-2-injector-instance-globally hope will help you

Comment: Hi @malbarmawi, When I type "const e =$0" into Chrome's devtoosl console, I get an "undefined" message.  The answer you referenced, that's TypeScript ... I'm trying to figure out how to access it from teh browser console, unless I'm misreading what's in the accepted answer.

Comment: $0 is just a ref for any item you have click on it in the element tab so just look for app-root and click on it then the $0 will point to that element

Comment: or this way `ng.probe(document.querySelector('app-root')).injector`

Comment: Thx.  If you are so inclined, I have a related question here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898015/in-angular-8-how-do-i-access-an-injected-service-from-the-browser-console .